# Whats the best and most impressive way to present your work to a client?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, print-design, photography

I'm going to be visiting some clients soon and want to try get some jobs. One of them is a photography job the other is a logo. I am experienced in both and in the past I've just taken an iPad and scrolled through some of my work. I want to step my game up so was wondering what would be the best option from the style to the File and device used.

Comment: I suggest pyrotechnics and sequins.

Comment: Do you have a webpage? Business cards? A printed brochure? A youtube channel? And what this have anything to do with Photoshop?

Comment: Somehow i get the feeling you dont actually want most impressive. You want most impressive in context X and budget Y. Which is different from most impressive. Since you dont tell X and Y the answer you got reflexmcts well what you really asked.

Answer (score 1):

Fly them to NYC, have a limo waiting to take them to Time's Square, have an ad you did for someone else on the big screen when you meet them there. Then have a considerable number of the crowd of Time's Square be a flash mob / mannequin challenge. All of them focused on the ad at once. Some with phones out taking pictures of it. Have the CEO of that other product there as well praising you, your work, and the viral marketing you just did for them. Hand the person an OMAS Fountainpen and a contract to sign. Have a second limo pull up, get in it, leave.